# Responsive sizing with paper.js

Tags: paperjs

wondering what the best way of creating responsive canvas sizes. At the moment I have to double up all my code using the following pattern

```
var cicrle = new Path.Circle({ radius: 40, fillColor: 'red' })
circle.position = view.center

view.onResise = function(event){
circle.position = view.center
}
```

This is ok for one item, but once the items start adding up it a lot of doubling up of code.

Is there a better way of doing things?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paper.js has 2 kinds of grouping classes: `Group` and `Layer`; if you update one of those's position, you'll update all its descendants positions at once.
By default, the created items are implicitely added to the active layer (`project.activeLayer`) so for a simple scene:

```js
project.activeLayer.position = view.center;
```

should do the trick.

See this [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.7/S/nVDBDoIwDP2VZRcgEuLFC8YTVw9Gj+JhjiKT2ZIxIEr4dxlGwlWbtE372vea9hzFA3jMTyVYWfCQS8pcjdCxg7BFlCgjNfh9alJko0lACyZmrYIu+hThFzMiU00ds816buVK64Q0jRseGYE38Bw0BFuXnP+ixFZL7r/k8galVYSM8Ai1eoEfsFmyMnQHaSMxjrSwF08wUUW1mhZ2y0smvsGF8WdXA6KsSKGteXy+DG8=) for a demonstration.

```js
new Path.Circle({
    center: view.center,
    radius: 50,
    fillColor: 'orange'
});

new Path.Circle({
    center: view.center + 50,
    radius: 50,
    fillColor: 'orange'
});

function onResize() {
    project.activeLayer.position = view.center;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks Sasensi. That is a good explanation thank you. How you go about resizing shapes in relation to the canvas size?

Comment: Could you give an example ? Maybe post it as a separate issue, I'll be happy to help.